# javascript alert value from a tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have on a page a tag links generated from a database with an id. What im trying to do is in an alert box display the text inside the a tag.

Ive tried to have a look to see if I can see a previous question, which I have come up with the following but all I get in the alert box is object HTMLCollection

I have the following code:

```
<a id="bet" onclick="addSlip();" class="btn btn-round" style="text-align: left;">'.$home->one.' <span>'.$home->two.'</span></a>
```

and...

```
function addSlip() {
    document.getElementById('bet').innerHTML=bet;
    alert(bet);
}
```

Thanks for any constructive answers

Comment: What exactly you want when user click on a tag it will show the inner html in alert?

Answer (score 2):

You should do the following

```
function addSlip() {
    var bet = document.getElementById('bet').textContent;
    alert(bet);
}
```

the rest as it is.

or using jquery

```
 function addSlip() {
        var bet = $("#bet").text()
        alert(bet);
    }
```

The main problem of your program was that the alerted variable had no value. (undefined)
The way you wrote it if the variable bet had a value would change the innerHTML of the of the a tag to that value.
Now to the using innerHTML or textContent part. As mentioned [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) in terms of performance the textContent is better

Comment: Yes, this is what is all about: to use either `.innerHTML` or `.textContent` property. But not an incorrect `.innerHTML.textContent`

Answer (score 0):

In your case alert will give you the HTML Object Collection only.

When you have an element with id, then you can access them anywhere in javascript

e.g. for the following HTML

```
<div id="bet">This is a div </div>
```

in JS

```
alert(bet);
```

will give you the html object collection.

Solution for you is update your code

```
function addSlip() {
    document.getElementById('bet').innerHTML=bet;
    alert(bet);
}
```

to

```
function addSlip() {

    alert( document.getElementById('bet').innerHTML);
}
```

If there is some html elements also in the div you can update the function with

```
function addSlip() {

        alert(document.getElementById('bet').textContent);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to reverse the variable assignment of `bet`:

```
function addSlip() {
    var bet = $("#bet").text();// or $("#bet").html() if you want the HTML alerted
    alert(bet);
}
```